# Unity 4k 360 Video for iOS and Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, mobile, 360-degrees

I would like to integrate a 360 video player into an existing app for mobile.

I use the Skybox/Panoramic shader and a RenderTexture for the Video pluged in the VideoPlayer component. In 2k (2048x1024 or 2048x2048 for 3D) everything is fine but when I try to take a 4k video (4096x2048 or 4096x4096 for 3D) the app crashes instantly on an iPhone 6 Plus. I also tested it with a video clip in 3840x1920 but all I got from the debugger is:

```
INFO [vr/gvr/capi/src/gvr.cc:116] Initialized GVR version 1.120.0
[VRDevice] Successfully created device cardboard.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

I thought, it has something to do with the max texture size but 4096x4096 should be OK for most devices today.

Do you guys have an idea whats going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: When your question is about a crash in your app, the most important thing to do is post the crash log. Without it, there is really no way to help you

Comment: @Programmer Hey, I added the crash log. But it's not really detailed.

Comment: That can't be the only issue. Enable debug mode the use xcode to get the complete crash log